# Error installing Steroids.js on Mac through Terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, terminal, steroids

I've been looking at Steroids as an alternative to PhoneGap for performance reasons.  I've tried installing it through Terminal, but I don't really know what I'm doing.  :)

I've gone through the documentation, but when I run this: `steroids create TestApp`, I get this error: `steroids: command not found`.

Also, after installing Node.js and running this line: `npm install steroids -g`, it outputs lines like this:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/steroids
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/steroids
```

etc.  At the end, I get this:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/graceful-fs/-/graceful-fs-1.1.14.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch/-/minimatch-0.2.9.tgz
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/MyUser/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have no idea what is going on here, so if you need more details, please let me know.  :)  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

EDIT:  I also get this error while the script is being run:  `npm ERR! registry error parsing json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the NPM registry is currently (as of 11/4/2013 5:44PM eastern time) down. You can check the status on their [status page](http://status.npmjs.org/).

Comment: Oh, well that would explain it!  Thank you very much, you saved me from hours of frustration... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with **sudo**

> sudo npm install steroids -g

Comment: I did try that as well, but got the same response.  I will try again.

Comment: One error that I get as well is: npm ERR! registry error parsing json